# Are atomic groups always used with alternation | inside?

Tags: regex

Are atomic groups always used with alternation `|` inside? I get the impression from "all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group" [from](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it,
>   automatically throws away **all backtracking positions remembered by any
>   tokens inside the group**. Atomic groups are non-capturing. The syntax
>   is (?>group).
>
> An example will make the behavior of atomic groups clear. The regular
>   expression a(bc|b)c (capturing group) matches abcc and abc. The regex
>   a(?>bc|b)c (atomic group) matches abcc but not abc.

Can you given an example, where atomic groups are used without alternation `|` inside it? Thanks.

Comment: The classical: `(?>a+)a` that is always failing.

Comment: or `"(?>a+b*)+"` instead of `"(?:a+b*)+"` that avoids a catastrophic backtracking with this kind of strings: `"ababbaaaabbababaabba`

Comment: Compare `(abc)?a` to `(?>(abc)?)a`. Only the first one finds a match in 'abc'.

Answer (score 3):

Alternations have nothing to do with atomic groups. The point of atomic groups is to avoid backtracking. There are two main reasons for this:

1. Avoid unneeded backtracking when a regex is going to fail to match anyway.
2. Avoid backtracking into a part of an expression where you don't want to find a match

You asked for an example of atomic grouping without alternations.

Let's look at both uses.

**A. Avoid Backtracking on Failure**

For example, consider these two strings:

```
name=Joe species=hamster food=carrot says:{I love carrots} 
name=Joe species=hamster food=carrot says:{I love peas}
```

Let's say we want to find a string that is well-formed (it has the `key=value` tokens) and has `carrots` after the tokens, perhaps in the `says` part. One way to attempt this could be:

**Non-Atomic Version**

```
^(?:\w+=\w+\s+)*.*carrots
```

This will match the first string and not the second. We're happy. Or... are we really? There are two reasons to be unhappy. We'll look at the second reason in part B (the second main reason for atomic groups). So what's the first reason?

Well, when you debug the failure case in RegexBuddy, you see that it takes the engine 401 steps before the engine decides it cannot match the second string. It is that long because after matching the tokens and failing to match `carrots` in the `says:{I love peas}`, the engine backtracks into the `(\w+=\w+\s+)*` in the hope of finding `carrots` there. Now let's look at an atomic version.

**An Atomic Version**

```
^(?>(?:\w+=\w+\s+)*).*carrots
```

Here, the atomic group prevents the engine from backtracking into the `(?:\w+=\w+\s+)*`. The result is that on the second string, the engine fails in 64 steps. Quite a lot faster than 401!

**B. Avoid Backtracking into part of String where Match is Not Desired**

Keeping the same regexes, let's modify the strings slightly:

```
name=Joe species=hamster food=carrots says:{I love carrots} 
name=Joe species=hamster food=carrots says:{I love peas}
```

Our atomic regex still works (it matches the first string but not the second).

However, the non-atomic regex now matches both strings! That is because after failing to find `carrots` in `says:{I love peas}`, the engine backtracks into the tokens, and finds `carrots` in `food=carrots`

Therefore, in this instance an atomic group is a handy tool to skip the portion of the string where we don't want to find `carrots`, while still making sure that it is well-formed.